# Active between a range of times

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datetime, if-statement

Is there a way to activate a message box during a range of times in c#. Can I have a message box that appears during 13:00 and 16:00 for example.

```
if(DateTime.TimeOfDay(13,0,0 to 16,0,0)
{
    messagebox.show("You need to feed the dog now");
}
```

If you have a solution to this problem please tell me because I have been stuck on this for a while.

This is the code I have so far.

```
if(theDate.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(11,59,0))
            {
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Good Morning");
            }
            else if(theDate.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0))
            {
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Good Evening");
            }
            else if(theDate.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0) && theDate.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(16, 59, 0))
            {
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Good Afternoon.");
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You didn't _even_ tell us. How do you think we can solve it without knowing it?

Comment: When I run this code it keeps saying "Good Morning" instead of skipping that and moving to the "Good Afternoon"

Comment: Did you debug you code and see what is your `theDate.TimeOfDay` exactly?

Comment: yes i have done that and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `<` and `>` operators to compare your `TimeSpan` values like;

```
var ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
if(ts > new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) && ts < new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0))
{
     MessageBox.Show("You need to feed the dog now");
}
```

Comment: @Sachin _doesn't work_ is **never** enough information that explain your problem. You get any error or exception? You should show the all relevant code when you asking a question.

Comment: if(theDate.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(11,59,0))
            {
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Good Morning");
            }
            else if(theDate.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0))
            {
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Good Evening");
            }
            else if(theDate.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0) && theDate.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(16, 59, 0))
            {
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Good Afternoon.");
            }

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear but this is what i have so far,

Comment: @Sachin Update this in your question with the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31356342/edit).

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the hour as limit, you can also do:

```
int thisHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
if(thisHour.CompareTo(13 - 1) + thisHour.CompareTo(16) == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You need to feed the dog now.");
}
```

Or, as to your expanded task:

```
int thisHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
string salutation = "Good Evening";

if(thisHour < 12)
{
    salutation = "Good Morning";
}
else if (thisHour < 17)
{
    salutation = "Good Afternoon";
}
synthesizer.SpeakAsync(salutation);
```